# How can I triangulate a mesh without changing the object?

Tags: python, uv, export, bmesh

I have to triangulate the object's mesh because the format I export to **only** understands **triangles**. Now I not only want to export geometry but **also the uv-mappings** for the mesh. Let's call the uv_texture `uvTex`. The context object is `obj` What I have done so far:

```
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)
# everything is fine so far
```

Now the problem is that you access the uv-data by iterating through the faces and then through their vertices. So for example `uvTex.data[0]` belongs to `obj.data.faces[0]."vertices[0]"` (quotes because it's not really a vertex in this context, it's just an index but you get what I mean).

Triangulating the mesh has changed the order of the vertices so my question is now:

*How does one export a triangulated version of an object's mesh, including uv-mappings, without changing the objects geometry, etc.?*

Comment: add Triangulate modifier?

Comment: that is in no way automated and **has to be done by the user**, (actually no) but how do I access the modified data without applying it? or should I rewind time after my script finished? enlighten me please

Comment: just add the modifier, on export the modifier will be applies. This is the non-destructive way. Does this do what you want?

Comment: it is my **own** export script, written, not finished, by me. Why should the modifier magically be applied on export?

Comment: come to chat please http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8888/the-renderfarm

Comment: Yoiu should correct the line "bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, bm.faces)" to "bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)" - just for the sake of a case somebody wanting to copy your code (currently this would yield an error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the UV and Texture / Image information with bmesh using the custom data layers:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
ob.update_from_editmode()
me = ob.data
vgroups = dict(enumerate(ob.vertex_groups.keys()))
vgroups_weights = [["%s: %.3f" % (vgroups[vg.group], vg.weight) for vg in v.groups] for v in me.vertices]

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)


uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.active
if uv_layer is None:
    raise Exception("No active UV map (uv)")

uv_tex = bm.faces.layers.tex.active
if uv_tex is None:
    raise Exception("No active UV map (tex)")

for face in bm.faces:
    print("Face %i, Image = %s" % (face.index, getattr(face[uv_tex].image, "name", "")))

    for loop, vert in zip(face.loops, face.verts):
        print(" - Loop for Vertex %i, UV = %r" % (vert.index, loop[uv_layer].uv))
    for vert in face.verts:
        print(" - %s" % ", ".join(vgroups_weights[vert.index]))

bm.free()
del bm
```

Verts and loops of a face should match (first vertex - first loop etc.)

Comment: Would it also be possible to retrieve vertex groups from a bmesh? If yes, could you include that in your answer?

Comment: No, it's not accessible via bmesh module. But since triangulation doesn't change or add vertices, the `BMVert`s should be in line with `MeshVertex`es. Added vertex group name and weight printing to the face loop, although it doesn't make sense to print weights per face-vertex.

Answer (score 3):

What me and Vader figured out together so far:

You can duplicate the object's data by calling

```
meshCopy = obj.to_mesh(scene, APPLY_MODIFIERS, 'PREVIEW')
```

This means that in order to do this you have to know a scene in which context you want to evaluate the modifier, limiting the export a bit but not hitting it hard. APPLY_MODIFIERS is a bool whether to apply modifiers or not so if this is False nothing will be changed. Not though that blender still doesn't accept None as scene so you might consider "cheating" and just handing over bpy.context.scene.

What you get is a perfect copy of `object.data` meaning that you can now "freely" modify "anything" you want. Instead of using `obj.data` you just have to use `meshCopy` now. Also most of the `bpy.ops` stuff won't work now but most of the time (at all times??) there is a second possibility. For example to triangulate the mesh you do this

```
import bmesh
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(mesh)
bmesh.ops.triangulate(bm, faces=bm.faces)
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()
del bm
```

I hope this helps anyone that may see this question in the future ;)

Comment: The bmesh module has its own `to_mesh()` method: `bm.from_object()` ([API Docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_10/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.from_object)). The equivalent would look like: `bm.from_object(obj, bpy.context.scene, deform=True, render=False` (`render=False` means `'PREVIEW'` quality)

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works, since around version 2.8. Lookup `evaluated_get` method in Blender documentation to see how it's done in the more recent API