# How to create a temporary mesh in object for exporting?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a temporary mesh in an object, so that I can perform various operations on it, such as apply modifiers, run operators and what not? Then export the object with a python script. Revert back the changes. The ultimate goal is to prepare object for export, export and then leave the original object intact.

Comment: You can do this, see related question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7033/how-can-i-triangulate-a-mesh-without-changing-the-object/7036#7036 (not duplicate but close)

Comment: I need to do some of bpy.ops stuff in between the modifiers. How can that be done? For example, I need to first triangulate, then do "seams from islands" operator, then apply another modifier.

Comment: Probably best create a copy of the object, operate on this, then remove after.

Comment: You could just duplicate your object in current form.  Alt+C convert it to mesh.  This applies all modifiers and such.  Export it and delete it.